# Map control not showing in design part in winphn7

Tags: windows-phone-7

[image]i am trying to create add map in windows phone 7 design part. but i followed all procedure.
If i drag map control from toolbox, the map will not show in design part. even i given credential provider.here the map not showing. i have attached screenshot please help.

this is my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,154,0,12">
        <my:Map Height="524" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Name="map1" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="474" 

                CredentialsProvider="Aj53qt4Oulu0Ez0IVGdNvTVy-swLfo7vCexVzJXJq7hGj1sBYTfSu2t4bPLero2P">
            <!--Enter your bing map key here-->

            <my:Pushpin Name="pin" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Visible">
                <my:Pushpin.Content>
                   <Ellipse Width="20" Height="15" Name="elps" />
                </my:Pushpin.Content>
            </my:Pushpin>
        </my:Map>
            <Button Content="+" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,52,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Background="#00270D0D" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="#FF3CAD0A" Foreground="#FFF62A15" FontSize="28" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Button Content="-" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,132,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Background="#00270D0D" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="#FFE61919" BorderBrush="#FF1FAA49" FontSize="28" Click="button2_Click" />
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Find" Grid.Row="1" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,83,0,0" Name="find" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="find_Click" />
    <Button Content="Change view" Grid.Row="1" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,83,12,0" Name="view" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="195" Click="view_Click" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,0,0,0" Name="txtbx" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="312" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Height="57" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,18,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Enter Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF569E9C" />
</Grid>

  ![this is my screenshot.][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EBGj.jpg
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. Map's wont be visible when you add that control. Just run the app in emulator or device, you can able to see maps. But your emulator or device should have active internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

The map control needs to do web requests to run which isn't allowed in the WP7 designer. So therefore you wont see anything.